# selecting different data types to create a view

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a view called customersummary that will have the customerID, firstname,lastname and the paper descriptions they are subscribed to but it gives me the error conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Journal'to data type smallint. I am not sure how to fix this

any help would be appreciated.

```
 Create view CustomerSummary
as
Select  distinct customer.customerID,firstname,lastname from customer
inner join customerpaper on customer.customerID = CustomerPaper.PaperID
inner join paper on customerPaper.PaperID = Paper.Description
```

Comment: `on customerPaper.PaperID = Paper.Description` looks suspicions. IDs usually `int` while Descriptions - not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The datatypes of the tables you are joining on don't match. You can convert or cast them in your view though.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

But it sounds like your joining on odd fields. I think you should check what the foreign keys are, I would imagine it would look something like this:

```
 Create view CustomerSummary
as
Select  distinct Customer.customerID, firstname, lastname from Customer
inner join CustomerPaper on Customer.customerID = CustomerPaper.CustomerID
inner join Paper on CustomerPaper.PaperID = Paper.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

The error comes out from the last line of query:
`customerPaper.PaperID = Paper.Description`
I think the `Paper.Description` Column should replace with some columns like `Paper.Id`. Or, if the `Paper.Description` Column really stores id for papers, you need to convert it to the "smallint" data type. Try `CONVERT(SMALLINT, Paper.Description)`.